# Hibernate. How can I add an entry to a table that has 2 foreign keys from 2 different tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables

1. User
2. Order
3. Invoice

**User** has @OnetoMany mapping to **Invoice** table and **Order** has @OnetoMany mapping to **Invoice** table. That means, **Invoice** table has 2 foreign keys, one coming from **User** table and the another from **Order** table (say 'user_fk' and 'order_fk').

In hibernate, I cannot add an invoice through user. It gives out an error saying that

> "The column 'order_fk' cannot be null"

The same happens when I try with **Order** table. I understood why this error is showing up. I want to know the solution for this. How can I add an entry to a table that has 2 foreign keys from 2 different tables in Hibernate ?

Comment: In case of @ManytoMany between two tables we having third table .. If you can think on similar lines for this scenario like having fourth or fifth table

Comment: @Sagii yeah having fourth and fifth table can be an option. But is there any better way to do it with 3 tables only ?

Answer (score 1):

You should first create both User and Order. Then instead of creating Invoice through User try to just create Invoice object with given User and Order. Saving such object should proceed without any issues.
If that doesn't help try to add schema of your database and code that you are using for creating and saving those objects to DB.

Comment: Got it, thanks!
Also, this means that every time I create an Invoice for a particular user_id and order_id, I should get both the User and Order objects from the database, right ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Here is a help how you can do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413145/7100461